# How to list all flatpak apps that use a specific runtime?

Tags: software-updates, flatpak

### Background

I got these messages when updating:

```bsh
Info: org.gnome.Platform is end-of-life, with reason: GNOME 3.24 runtime is no longer supported as of 11th January 2019. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.
Info: org.gnome.Platform.Locale is end-of-life, with reason: GNOME 3.24 runtime is no longer supported as of 11th January 2019. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.
```

As this is a runtime, I now want to find out, which app(s) is/are actually using this outdated runtime, so I can report it as a bug there.

Basically, I just want to do what the message told me…

### Question

So, given a name of a runtime (`org.gnome.Platform`) and a version of a runtime (3.24) **how can I list all apps that use this runtime in this specific version**?

Also, please answer the simpler case without a specific version, so how can I list all apps that use a specific runtime (`org.gnome.Platform`)?

### Tries so far

- `flatpak info --show-runtime <appid>` shows the runtime of a specific app… But well… I can hardly do this manually for each app.
- `flatpak list --app` shows all apps, but no runtime information. Even `flatpak list --app --columns=all` does not show something specific.
- `flatpak list --runtime` show all runtimes including the version (nice), but not, which apps actually make use of it.
- I can use `flatpak info org.gnome.Platform//3.24` to show information about the runtime, but I have still no idea what app uses it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatpak list --app` with the `--app-runtime` option:

```bsh
flatpak list --app --app-runtime org.gnome.Platform//3.30
```

If you uninstall those apps to clean-up some space, remember to also:

```bsh
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this won't answer your specific question, but it just might solve your problem.

I was looking at the flatpak reference guide on ITSFOSS Blog, and I found the following command...

```
$ flatpak uninstall --unused
```

(I have a ton of flatpaks installed, and it took my slow i3 x131e Lenovo ThinkPad w/ 8gb ram and a spinning rust HDD about 5-10 minutes to run)

After that I did the command below again:

```
$ flatpak update
```

(no errors this time)

Even though I was having issues w/ Gnome and KDE(freedesktop) runtimes, the uninstall only appeared to uninstall a half dozen or so KDE runtimes, and a couple of versions of a GTK+ app(pulse-effects); but it did get rid of the errors for me.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a nice tip, but really does not solve my problem. Because in my case, that old runtime was actually not unused, but in use by a flatpak…

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
flatpak list --app --columns=application,runtime
```

- `--app` argument is used to **list** only the apps installed.
- `--columns` argument is used to decide **how to** order the columns that are showing in terminal, in this case is `application` and `runtime`

console returns:

```
Application ID                          Runtime
com.discordapp.Discord                  org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
com.getpostman.Postman                  org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
com.github.artemanufrij.playmymusic     org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40
com.github.fabiocolacio.marker          org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/41
com.github.jeromerobert.pdfarranger     org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40
com.github.phase1geo.minder             org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
com.slack.Slack                         org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
com.spotify.Client                      org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
de.haeckerfelix.Shortwave               org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40
info.smplayer.SMPlayer                  org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15
io.atom.Atom                            org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/20.08
io.github.OpenToonz                     org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15
org.geany.Geany                         org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/40
org.gnome.GTG                           org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40
org.inkscape.Inkscape                   org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/41
org.kde.kdenlive                        org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15
org.kde.okular                          org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15
org.libreoffice.LibreOffice             org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
org.mozilla.firefox                     org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
org.phoenicis.playonlinux               org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08
org.synfig.SynfigStudio                 org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.38
org.telegram.desktop                    org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
org.videolan.VLC                        org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15
us.zoom.Zoom                            org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
work.openpaper.Paperwork                org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/40
```

you have many options for ordering the columns to display, examples:

- `--columns=name,size`
- `--columns=name,version`
- `--columns=name,branch`
- `--columns=name,ref`
- `--columns=name,latest`